# Error: request for member ‘****’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have 2 structs using pointers to form a linked list.

```
typedef struct { 
    char *text;
    int count;
} *Item;

typedef struct node {
    Item item;
    struct node *next;
} *link;
```

Im trying to create a bunch of operations over this type but I'm having a lot of problems with this particular function.

> error: request for member ‘text’ in something not a structure or union
>     strcpy(new->item->text, buffer->text);
>
> error: request for member ‘text’ in something not a structure or union
>     new->item->text = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer->text)+1));

Basically the error is on the **buffer->text** pass, but I've been messing around with it for the past hour and can't seem to find what's wrong with it. I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't wrap my hear around it anymore.

```
link new_item(Item* buffer) {
   link new = (link) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   new->item->text = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer->text)+1));
   strcpy(new->item->text, buffer->text);
   new->item->count = 1;
   new->next = NULL;
   return new;
}
```

Comment: The message sometimes means you're using `.` where `->` should be used, or vice versa.  Alternatively, it means that the LHS of the reference is neither a pointer to a structure nor a structure; and that's your problem here.  See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — the answer's "No" because it leads to problems like this.  The variable `buffer` is a pointer to a pointer to a structure; you need to use `(*buffer)->text` etc.  Or you need to change the function to `link new_item(Item buffer)`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have two levels of indirection instead of just one.  Specifically, `buffer` has type `Item *`, while `Item` is a `struct {...} *`.  You probably want to change `Item *buffer` to just `Item buffer`.  If you really need two levels of indirection, then you would need to do `(*buffer)->text` to access the `text` field, but this probably isn't what you want.

This is one of the reasons why many people advise against [using `typedef` to define pointer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers), as it can often lead to mistakes like this.